# How to configure com.sun.net.httpserver to accept only requests from localhost?

Tags: java, httpserver

I am using the com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer to handle some http requests. My http server runs behind nginx that maps the server domain names and forward the requests to my server by using it as a proxy running at a certain port. My http server takes all requests if they access the port where the server is running. I want a mechnism so that the server accept only requests from a domain that is supposed to be available, the same I use with nginx. I guess it would help if I could force the http server to be accessable by localhost only.

What would be the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I guess it would help if I could force the http server to be accessable by localhost only.

A Java SE `HttpServer` instance<sup>1</sup> listens for requests on the IP address that it is bound to<sup>2</sup>.  So bind it to a loopback IP address like this:

```
InetAddress localHost = InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress();
InetSocketAddress sockAddr = new InetSocketAddress(localHost, 80);
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(sockAddr, 0);
```

More generally, if you only want to accept requests from a given set of IP addresses, one approach would be to call `HttpExchange::getRemoteAddress` in your handler and act appropriately if the remote address is not what you want.  But beware that the remote address is going to be the immediate upstream IP address.  It could be your reverse proxy, or some forward proxy used by the remote user.

But if you are looking for something where you can accept all request but only respond to requests that are addressed to a specific domain names (as per a conventional vhosts file)  I think you are going to have to implement that filtering yourself.  `HttpServer` is designed to be a simple light-weight server ... not a full functionality web container.

---

<sup>1 - This only applies to the `HTTPServer` classes provided by the JDK.  For others, YMMV.

2 - Unless you bind to the wild-card address ...</sup>

Comment: This is exactly the answer I have searched for, here you will find the most knowledgeable users. Btw, do you think its a bad idea to use the http server from that package? Its still part of the api and I do not know why most frameworks prefer tomcat or other heavy weight servers if you have the jdk server already. What is your opinion?

Comment: The "heavy-weight" servers are (variously) offering better performance, more advanced functionality, more flexibility, etcetera.  Make your choices based on what you need.